# Django rest framework serializer with extra field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a django app in which i am using Django Rest Framework!

I have a model as follows:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I have the serializer defined as follows:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
```

In my view, i have a query as follows:

```
author_detail = Author.objects.extra(select={'middle_name':'''SELECT middle_name from MyTable where MyTable.first_name = first_name'''})
```

According to the query, i will be getting an extra field in my objects called `middle_name`. But i cannot use the serializer on the resulting object anymore because it will not bring the `middle_name` in the api.

How do i modify my serializer to get the `middle_name` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the field in the serializer as a normal field.

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    middle_name = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'middle_name', 'email')
```

Comment: I believe you don't even need the definition, you should be able to just add it in `Meta`. That's what the doc says anyway, I didn't try it.